# Cómo ejecutar un procedure de genexus en linea de comandos

Tags: genexus

Estuve viendo algunas soluciones en ésta misma plataforma pero la verdad es que no entiendo muy bien sus explicaciones. Soy nuevo en genexus.

Esto fue lo que hice:

[image: Coloqué call protocoll= command line]

luego en cmd intenté: java -cp "ruta_del_procedure\anombre_del_procedure"

lo coloqué con el prefijo "a"

también intenté de esta forma:

java com.genexus.GXDaemon com.test.nombre_del_procedure

pero me salta error de que no encuentra la clase principal com.genexus.GXDaemon

Answer (score 1):

No se exactamente que es lo que estas intentando hacer, pero genexus te ofrece la posibilidad de ejecutar como command line directo en el IDE. Boton derecho al objecto > Run with this only. Y en el output podrias ver el resultado de lo que estas haciendo. Para ver valores de variables o resultados deberias usar la siguiente linea:

```
msg(&variable, status)
```

En ese caso te mostraria el valor de la variable en el output de genexus.
Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación oficial](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?16034,HowTo%3A%20Execute%20main%20Java%20programs%20by%20command%20Line), debes ejecutar el siguiente comando, estando parado en la raíz de tu environment:

```
"<JavaPath>\bin\java.exe" -cp <classpath> <NameSpace>.a<MainObject>
```

**JavaPath**: ruta donde la versión de Java está instalada.

**classpath**: ruta donde están los archivos compilados de las clases. En este ejemplo:
web\build\classes\java\main;"web\build\libs*"

**NameSpace**: nameSpace usado en el proyecto.

**MainObject**: nombre del objeto main que se quiere ejecutar, en tu caso "nombre_del_procedure".

Suponiendo que tengas instalado el JDK 18 en la carpeta *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1* y que el nombre de tu KB sea *KBEjemplo*, por lo tanto el directorio raíz de tu environment sería: *C:\Models\KBEjemplo\JavaModel*

Estando parado en C:\Models\KBEjemplo\JavaModel>, deberías ejecutar

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe" -cp web\build\classes\java\main;"web\build\libs\*" com.KBEjemplo.nombre_del_procedure
```